Query Volusion for recent orders
I've done some googling and also have spent a few hours on the phone with Volusion.
I was told by their support team that there is no supported way to programmatically get recent orders.
I had initially found via Google this page on webhooks: https://developer.v2-dev.volusion.com/api-reference/#/app/webhooks-post
But was told that webhooks are deprected. It seems in fact that their whole API is deprecated.
In the admin interface you can create "Saved Queries". But I was told that there's no way to run a saved query via HTTP.
This article says that custom sql can be uploaded via SFTP and then invoked:
How to connect Volusion DB without using admin panel
But Volusion said that while it's possible, it isn't supported.
They also don't have a network of paid consultants (I'd be happy to pay). I expect that we'll be moving off of Volusion some day, but today I need to setup some automation. I just want to either be notified (webhook) of new orders or have a URL that will return new orders.
I'm happy to write sql and upload it. But they don't have a published schema for their database. Hoping someone can fill in the missing links on getting data out of Volusion in an automated manner.

My company was on Volusion for about 7 years.  Terrible.  Switched to Shopify, phew!  Volusion won't support anything - you gotta do it yourself.
We created two files (.sql and .xsd - see below) and placed them in the v/vspfiles/schema/Generic folder.  Then from code, you can call it like an API, like this...
http://www.yoursite.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=username@yoursite.com&EncryptedPassword=XXXXXXXXX&EDI_Name=Generic\MyOrders
After you process the order, switch the status from Processing to ReadyToShip to prevent it from being looked at again.  You can do that through code by creating/manipulating a file and executing it just like the orders fetch.  Let me know if you need more details.  Or you could add to the WHERE clause to get orders placed in the last day or so.  Good luck!
Here's a bunch of schema
https://volusionhome.my.site.com/knowledgebase/s/article/DeveloperResources
MyOrders.sql
select 
a.cnt as 'ProductCount'
,o.OrderID
,o.OrderDate
,o.OrderStatus
,PaymentAmount
,od.ProductPrice
,Quantity
,PaymentMethodID
,TotalShippingCost
,SalesTaxRate1
,SalesTaxRate2
,SalesTaxRate3
,od.ProductCode
,od.ProductName
,CouponCode
,Order_Comments
,EmailAddress
,BillingFirstName
,BillingLastName
,BillingPhoneNumber
,ShipFirstName
,ShipLastName
,ShipAddress1
,ShipAddress2
,ShipCity
,ShipState
,ShipPostalCode
,ShipCountry 
,ShippingMethodName
from Orders o  
inner join OrderDetails od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID  
inner join Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
left outer join Products_Joined pj on pj.ProductCode = od.ProductCode 
left outer join ShippingMethods sm on sm.shippingMethodId = o.shippingMethodId
inner join 
    (SELECT oo.Orderid ,sum(Quantity) AS cnt 
    FROM Orders oo 
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails ood ON ood.OrderID = oo.OrderID 
    WHERE oo.OrderStatus = 'Processing' 
    and ProductCode not like 'DSC-%'
    group by oo.OrderId) 
        a on a.orderid = o.orderid 
where o.OrderStatus = 'Processing'

MyOrders.xsd (doesn't really matter too much what's in here...)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema id="xmldata" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
      <xs:element name="xmldata" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Orders">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" msprop:SqlDbType="Int" name="OrderID" msprop:TableNameXsd="Orders" msprop:IsIdentity="true" msprop:SQLTableAlias="o" />
                  <xs:element name="BillingFirstName" msprop:SqlDbType="VarChar" minOccurs="0" msprop:SQLTableAlias="o" msprop:maxLength="50" />
                  <xs:element name="BillingLastName" msprop:SqlDbType="VarChar" minOccurs="0" msprop:SQLTableAlias="o" msprop:maxLength="50" />
                  <xs:element name="OrderStatus" msprop:SqlDbType="VarChar" minOccurs="0" msprop:SQLTableAlias="o" msprop:maxLength="50" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


You mean that you can change the status by creating and running a sql file with an update statement?

I tested an update query on orders and it works

Yup - best of luck!
